# Transform columns to rows with a twist

Tags: google-sheets, unpivot

I have a table that is formatted like this:

```
SKU | Variant 1 | Variant 2 | Variant 3
0001 | Blue | Red | Green 
0002 | Black | white | Yellow
```

What I want to achieve is something like this bellow, basically displaying each variant from above on a separate row, but maintaining the sku in front.

```
SKU | Variants
0001 | Blue
0001 | Red
0001 | Green
0002 | Black
0002 | White
0002 | Yellow
```

I'm looking for a script to achieve this result in Google Sheets.

Comment: This is an **unpivot** operation. Plenty of examples here on SO.

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("♀",JOIN("♂",{A1,B1}),
                                                   JOIN("♂",{A1,C1}),
                                                   JOIN("♂",{A1,D1})),"♀")), 
                                                   "♂"),"0000"))`

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask] an be specific regarding if you are looking for a formula or a script.

Answer (score 1):

the formula you are looking for is:

> **`=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("♀",JOIN("♂",{A1,B1}),
>                                                    JOIN("♂",{A1,C1}),
>                                                    JOIN("♂",{A1,D1})),"♀")), 
>                                                    "♂"),"0000"))`**